# Change same factors across dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 y = c("D", "B", "E"),
                 z = c("H", "A", "B"))
```

I want to transform it like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 y = c("D", "B1", "E"),
                 z = c("H", "A1", "B2"))
```

So, whenever I have same factor in different column I want to add number to it in sequential order.

Comment: In `df1`, is the `B` in column `y` intended to be `B1`?

Comment: Are values never repeated within a column?

Comment: Values are repeated in column and they should stay like that, I just don't want them to repeat across different columns

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(-id) |> 
  group_by(value) |> 
  mutate(unique = row_number(),
         value = paste0(value, if_else(unique == 1, "", as.character(unique-1)))) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  select(-unique) |>
  pivot_wider() |> 
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  x     y     z    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     D     H    
2 B     B1    A1   
3 C     E     B2
```

---

Your further request was a very difficult problem to wrangle, and this is the best I could do with it. It's extremely inelegant and hackish, unfortunately:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "A", "C"), y = c("A", "B", "A"), z = c("H", "A", "B"))

reference_df <- tibble(name = names(df), pos = seq_along(names(df)))

first_instance <- df |> 
  pivot_longer(everything()) |> 
  left_join(reference_df) |> 
  group_by(value) |> 
  filter(pos == min(pos)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  distinct() |> 
  mutate(first = TRUE)

df |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(-id) |>
  left_join(reference_df) |>
  left_join(first_instance) |> 
  arrange(value, name) |> 
  group_by(value) |> 
  mutate(instances = if_else(first, 1, pos, missing = pos),
         instances2 = lag(instances) + 1,
         instances = if_else(instances > instances2, instances2, instances, missing = instances)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(value = if_else(instances > 1, paste0(value, instances-1), value)) |> 
  select(id, name, value) |> 
  pivot_wider() |> 
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  x     y     z    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     A1    H    
2 A     B     A2   
3 C     A1    B1
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know do I need to open another question. I want to add a number only to the values that appear in previous columns.
So, if I have

df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "A", "C"), y = c("A", "B", "A"), z = c("H", "A", "B"))

I want the output to be
x = c("A", "A", "C"), y = c("A1", "B", "A1"), z = c("H", "A2", "B1"))

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: Phil, I'll test this on a larger dataframe and let you know if it works. Thank you for your valuable time

Comment: Dear Phil, I tested the code on a larger dataframe. While it worked on the previous dataframe, on the new sample the result is a bit problematic. Values in the dataframe are not in the place where they should be after the process. So I modified your code a bit and now it works elegantly. I am attaching the updated code in response to the question. I am immensely grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This process is largely based on Phil's approach.

```
df = data.frame(x = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 16, replace = T),
                y = sample(LETTERS[3:7], 16, replace = T),
                z = sample(LETTERS[2:6], 16, replace = T))

reference_df <- tibble(name = names(df), pos = seq_along(names(df)))

first_instance <- df |> 
 pivot_longer(everything()) |> 
 left_join(reference_df) |> 
 group_by(value) |> 
 filter(pos == min(pos)) |> 
 ungroup() |> 
 distinct() |> 
 mutate(first = TRUE)

df1 <- df |> 
 mutate(id = row_number()) |> 
 pivot_longer(-id) |>
 left_join(reference_df) |>
 left_join(first_instance) |> 
 arrange(value, name) |> 
 group_by(value) |> 
 mutate(instances = if_else(first, 1, pos, missing = pos),
        instances2 = lag(instances) + 1,
        instances = if_else(instances > instances2, instances2, instances, missing = instances)) |> 
 ungroup() |> 
 mutate(value = if_else(instances > 1, paste0(value, instances-1), value)) |> 
 select(id, name, value) |> 
 pivot_wider()

df1 <- df1[names(df)] |> 
 arrange(df1, df1$id)

df1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).